# Free, web-based, open-ballot voting software

Tags: web-apps, self-hosted, voting

I am looking for open-ballot voting software that is [free](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) and can be self-hosted on a GNU/Linux server.  Basically, I would like something that:

- allows the software administrators to define a voter roll, the questions to be put to the vote, and the voting period;
- sends each voter in the roll a unique ballot by e-mail (or rather, sends them a unique link to a web-based voting interface);
- allows voters to review the options for each question via the web interface;
- allows voters to cast support/oppose/abstain votes for each question via the web interface, provided it's done within the voting period;
- ensures that votes are unique, verifiable, and tamper-proof; and
- makes the identities of all voters, and how they voted, available to the software's administrators (or perhaps even to all other voters).

All the free voting software I'm aware of, including [Helios](https://vote.heliosvoting.org/) and [VotoSocial](https://votosocial.github.io/), supports only secret ballots, where the votes are collected in such a way that no one can discover how a voter voted.  But open ballots are important in many use cases—for example, when a legislature considers a bill, it's important that people can discover how their elected representatives voted, and the same argument can be made for scrutinizing the work of decision-making bodies elected by membership-based organizations.